# R neural net training and prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, r-squared

I am trying to form a model on a set of data that I gathered from MT4. The OHLC and some MA slopes.

I am trying to get the best guess for price change in the future.

I am using

```
# Packages
require(quantmod) #for Lag()
require(nnet)
require(caret)

#Fit model
model <- train(change ~ Lag(change) + high + low + slope13 + slope50 + slope200, mt4,    
method='nnet', linout=TRUE, trace = FALSE,
           #Grid of tuning parameters to try:
           tuneGrid=expand.grid(.size=c(1,5,10),.decay=c(0,0.001,0.1))) 
ps <- predict(model, mt4)

#Examine results
model
plot(CHANGE)
lines(ps, col=2)
```

The output from the model is not so good from what I understand from the RSquared.

```
6828 samples
   6 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrap (25 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 6828, 6828, 6828, 6828, 6828, 6828, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  decay  RMSE     Rsquared  RMSE SD   Rsquared SD
  1     0      0.00483  0.00021   0.000124  0.000262   
  1     0.001  0.00483  0.000464  0.000124  0.000669   
  1     0.1    0.00483  0.00115   0.000125  0.0016     
  5     0      0.00499  0.000452  0.00074   0.000537   
  5     0.001  0.00484  0.000271  0.000123  0.000356   
  5     0.1    0.00485  0.00109   0.000131  0.00183    
  10    0      0.00485  0.00087   0.00012   0.00129    
  10    0.001  0.00486  0.000408  0.000121  0.000699   
  10    0.1    0.005    0.000638  0.000434  0.00121
```

Questions:

1. Am I training my model incorrectly because of such the bad output?
2. How do I get the best guess for the next bars change that I am training for? Even though this model appears horrible it would be nice to know how to get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results look about right to me.  Predicted prices changes in financial markets is **difficult**.

Also, when cross-validating time series data, you can't randomly assign each observation to a fold (this is what caret does).  You need to be aware of the time-series structure of your data.  Take a look at [this code](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/tscvexample/) for some examples.